# Android Horizontal Scroll View Picker - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to implement a picker. On the image below when the user swipes to the left Breakfast would be selected and the results would appear, You could also if you were on Breakfast press Dinner and it would smoothly scroll to Dinner. The XML I have so far is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarSize="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Breakfast" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Lunch" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dinner"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am not too sure this is the best way to go about it I would also like the little green bar to be displayed under the select option like in the image below. Any pointers or help would be really appreciated. Would love to know if Im on the right lines with the XML and if you could point me in the right direction of how to make the picker in code also that would be great!

J
[image]

Comment: Are you going to use the picker as a tab menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not too sure this is the best way to go about it I would also like the little green bar to be displayed under the select option like in the image below.

The common way to implement such a view is to use `ViewPager` with Indicator in Android. You can use some libs to simplify this work, for example [ViewPagerIndicator](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/ViewPagerIndicator/), and there are samples you may take a look.

Or you can try to create your own one. As you did in your code, use a `HorizontalScrollView` to create an indicator. So you're in the right direction to create an indicator, just use `ViewPager` with your indicator and set a scroll listener to them.

Comment: Thank You! this is perfect.